# How to detect if the requests to your server are coming from trustworthy service ? (in Django)

Tags: django

I have a 3rd party service that i've configured a webhook that triggers posting data on my url address. Now i want to restrict incoming requests to be allowed only for this service. How can i do this in Django ? Is there any trick on applying some security measures?

i'd be glad if you can provide some code snippets, please

**EDITED**
I can't count on the ip address of the requester, it can change in any time. I should use domain name i think

**EDITED 2**
I have a header called HTTP_X_REAL_IP, that contains the ip address of the service. Can i count on that header by comparing the socket ip address with properly received header ?

Comment: That depends. Do you know for instance the IP address of the requester?

Comment: WillemVanOnsem, i've edited the topic on this, i think that it's better to use domain name ... and 
 may be SSL certificates

Comment: What API is providing the web hook? Normally there is a documented way of verifying that it came from them.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, i have searched for docs on that topic, but there is no necessary infomation specifically about that.

Comment: Does the API that is accessing your webhook have any measures to validate the message came from them?  This is pretty standard now days.  Usually this comes in the form of some token, or even the entire message being sent to the known API, and it will respond with a signal that tells you it is actually from them.

Comment: @TimmSimpkins i can tell you that documentations have no words about that, [here are the docs](https://developers.amocrm.com/rest_api/#webhooks).  I am trying now to do some inspections for request headers to get a clear answer on that. It takes time for me because of some access difficulties (too much to describe it) but anyway I will do it in the end.

Comment: @DanielRoseman , may i ask you, I have a header called HTTP_X_REAL_IP, that contains the ip address of the service. Can i count on that header by comparing the socket ip address with properly received header ? (i have edited this post with some new info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that they don't have anything set up to easily do a test, and you aren't saying exactly what you are doing with this API, but it appears that you can query their API for information regarding a bunch of things.

What I would do is to take the information they sent you and send it back in a query to see if the information they now have matches the change they are telling you they made.  If they match, it is authentic.  If they don't match, discard it.

That's about the best I can tell you to do.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use the domain name, as you don't have it when processing a request (note that normally most requesters - internet users - don't have domain names, they only have IP addresses).

The simplest solution is to add an authentication key as required parameter to your APIs. Then, you process only those API calls which provide valid authentication key.

Comment: I have described that i don't want regular users to access this endpoint. I have a 3rd party service that posts data on my url and i am processing the data on my server side. i want to restrict others from posting data.

Comment: I understand and my answer is valid for your case. Add a required parameter such as key=mysecretpasswordwhichonlytrustedserviceknows to your API and noone else will be able to use it

Comment: okey now i see that, sorry. But this 3rd party service can't be configured to authenticate on my side... it has just a webhook url to be entered and then it posts data on my side if specific events occurred

Comment: In this case maybe you can ask their support first. Your solution with checking domain name (simplest solution with socket.gethostbyname(x)) may work if they use the same IP, but it is not guaranteed, especially if they have larger infrastructure with load balancers etc

Comment: I will ask their support, because of no good answer found yet... I want to ask you what do you think about crafting requests with specific headers ? that means i can't trust the one who posts data having specific header set.